# QGIS GeoServer response "Server replied: Forbidden"

Tags: qgis, mapserver, server

I have the following problem. I have created a WCS with Mapserver (MS4W) and would like to integrate it into QGIS. The URL request in the browser via KVP works perfectly. However, I get the error message with QGIS: "Answer not understood: (...) Server replied: Forbidden"

What could be the Problem?

The Error Logs in Apache, Mapserver und QGIS have no clues.

Comment: you haven't sent the correct username/password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution. I have specified a proxy in the network-settings and the service request had a problem if the geo-service-server is on the local server. I have to exclude the URL: "http: // localhost ...".